# DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module

Tags: python

I run this `pip install opencv-contrib-python` on the terminal and I received these error:

```
    Collecting opencv-contrib-python
  Using cached opencv-contrib-python-4.9.0.80.tar.gz (152.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  [86 lines of output]
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_machine == "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system != "Darwin"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Darwin"' don't match your environment
  Collecting cmake>=3.1
    Using cached cmake-3.28.1.tar.gz (42 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
  Collecting numpy==1.22.2
    Using cached numpy-1.22.2.zip (11.4 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1

    [47 lines of output]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
        backend = _build_backend()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
        obj = import_module(mod_path)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 944, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:/Users/bao15/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-37yuw_7d/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 242, in <module>
        monkey.patch_all()
      File "C:/Users/bao15/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-37yuw_7d/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all
        patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
      File "C:/Users/bao15/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-37yuw_7d/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/monkey.py", line 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
        patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:/Users/bao15/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-37yuw_7d/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params
        mod = import_module(mod_name)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 944, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:/Users/bao15/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-37yuw_7d/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
        raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
    [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I think that this is because of the C++ msys2 that I installed on my laptop, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: it might be useful to add a bit more system information here - what version of python are you using? What's your OS?

Comment: @pipscriv Yeah, My python version that I was using was Python 18 and my os is window 11. But the problem is solved when I install pycharm. The ide installation, somehow fix the bug::))

Comment: VC6 is from around 1998, so obsolete. In any case, you're not programming here but simply installing some software, making it off-topic here. For a proper question, you'd have to extract a [mcve] first. As it stands though, that would be worth a bug ticket instead.